# What is the difference from monero-blockchain-prune-known-spent-data and monero-blockchain-prune commands?

Tags: blockchain, pruning

I'm pruning my monero blockchain, but I see there are 2 commands:

- monero-blockchain-prune-known-spent-data
- monero-blockchain-prune

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`monero-blockchain-prune-known-spent-data` (an older tool) prunes specific pre-RCT known spent outputs and `monero-blockchain-prune` prunes the whole blockchain (a newer tool). You only need run the newer tool.